# How to get sharepoint file custom metadata using PnP.js

Tags: sharepoint, pnp-js

Using PnP.js, I can get the files under a folder

```
const files = await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/mysite/mylib/docs").files.get();
```

But it doesn't return the custom metadata for the files. It only returns the standard column values (such as Title, Name, TimeLastModified, ...). How to get all the metadata for files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem and the solution for me was to expand deferred property of files like this:

```
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativePath(...).files.expand('ListItemAllFields', 'Author').get();
```